# Insert into database using dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, insert

I have two dropdownlists that I populated with sqldatasources because of the mass quantity of items. My plan is to select an item from both lists and be able to insert it into the table. Essentially these are going to display a new record for a new established relationship. 
This is what I have so far.

Edited: My ASP file and how I populate my DropDownLists

```
 ServerID 
 <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" 
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="ServerID" 
    DataValueField="ServerID">
 </asp:DropDownList>
 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:NewAppInventoryConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT [ServerID] FROM [ServerDB_]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
  <br />

 DatabaseID
 <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" 
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DataTextField="DatabaseID" 
    DataValueField="DatabaseID">
 </asp:DropDownList>
 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:NewAppInventoryConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT [DatabaseID] FROM [ServerDB_]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

And my code behind file

```
 string ServerDropDown = DropDownList1.Text;
 string DBDropDown = DropDownList2.Text;

 SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["NewAppInventoryConnectionString"].ToString());
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO ServerDB_ (ServerID) VALUES (@ServerID)";
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO ServerDB_ (DatabaseID) VALUES (@DatabaseID)";
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ServerID", SqlDbType.Int);
    cmd.Parameters["@ServerID"].Value = ServerDropDown;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@DatabaseID", SqlDbType.Int);
    cmd.Parameters["@DatabaseID"].Value = DBDropDown;

    cmd.Connection = conn;

    conn.Open();

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    conn.Close();
```

I don't get any errors but it's not inserting like it's supposed to. I'm not really sure what to do, I've based all this off of tutorials like this one:

[Asp.Net inserting data into a database using a textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22436205/asp-net-inserting-data-into-a-database-using-a-textbox)

Comment: Is ServerDB_ the name of the table or the database?  It should be the name of the table. Secondly, you are setting the value of the parameter to a string when you told it it's SqlDbType is an Int.  Try casting the DropDownList1.Text to an integer first and set the value to that.

Comment: That is the name of my table. See I wasn't sure what I was supossed to do because my ID values are ints, so I knew the SqlDbType had to be an int. I don't know exactly how to cast the dropdownlist to an integer though.

Comment: try `int ServerDropDown = Convert.ToInt32(DropDownList1.Text);`

Comment: I think we are getting closer, but it's still not inserting. I'm wondering it if has to do with my tables now.

Comment: I think it's because of your dropdowns.  Drop down options have text (what's displayed) and a value.  The text would be a something like "Ford" where the value would be "0".  You need to make sure the value of the dropdown is valid ID to go into your table.  Then cast the value to a string, not the text.

Comment: Alos, once you get all of this working, I would recommend not doing inserts with application sql queries and instead make stored procedures to do your inserts or updates, and call the stored procedure in your application code.  Unless your using an ORM/Mirco ORM then it's a different ball game.  Doing so gives you the luxury of not having to modify application code to fix/update your insert/update queries, assuming the parameters for the stored procedure don't change.

Comment: Yea, I'm using someone else's database and kind of continuing where they left off, so stored procedures are a no go. But normally i would do that.

Comment: you should edit your question to include how you fill the drop down lists, and some schema info from your database. that would help us help you.

Comment: Just added that @DrewJordan.

Comment: still need some schema info... but what I THINK is happening is you have a single table (ServerDB_) with at least two columns (ServerID and DatabaseID). you select all values for each drop down, and would like to insert a new row if there isn't already a row with the current Server and Database selected by the user.

If that's the case, you should use a single `INSERT INTO ServerDB_ (ServerID, DatabaseID) VALUES (@ServerID, @DatabaseID)`. you should also be checking that the row doesn't exist already.

Comment: Correct. These values are supposed to represent a relationship between the servers and database. Sorry I only half read your request from before as I was currently in the process of doing that.

Comment: In lieu of your schema, see the edit to my previous comment. Also, keep in mind that this will create duplicate values in your lists, unless you `SELECT DISTINCT` from the table in your select commands.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
string ServerDropDown = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text;
string DBDropDown = DropDownList2.SelectedItem.Text;

SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["NewAppInventoryConnectionString"].ToString());
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

cmd.Connection = conn;

try{
    conn.Open();    
      //is ServerDB_ the table name?
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO ServerDB_ (ServerID, DatabaseID) VALUES (@ServerID, @DatabaseID)";

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ServerID", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
    cmd.Parameters["@ServerID"].Value = ServerDropDown;

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@DatabaseID", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
    cmd.Parameters["@DatabaseID"].Value = DBDropDown;

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
} 
catch(Exception ex)
{
    //do something with exception
}
 finally
{
    conn.Close();
}
```